# Git Error when try to pull from Git master branch in Katalon Studio

Tags: git, katalon-studio

I'm facing issues when try to pull from Git master branch.

[Here is the Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06Kyb.png)

Katalon build on top of the Eclips IDE so any help regrading this issue in Eclip as well ?

Comment: Do you have any changes of _tracked_ files (files git knows about) which _haven’t_ been committed?

Comment: Yeah able to resolve  its just conflicting with previous Test Suit files